# When attempting to add a new item to a list I am erasing the list instead of creating a new object to add to the list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, static-methods

Currently I have two buttons. One creates a Patient object and adds charge details to it and will continue to add additional copies of those details for each click and then adds those to the Patientlist.

The second button is supposed to create a new instance of the Patient object so that it can also then go through the same process as outlined above.

The problem is that when the second button is pressed it creates a new instance of the Patient object but the list loses the previous patient object.

I feel like I am missing something entirely too obvious here and have gone back through pluralsight videos, youtube tutorials, and quite a few questions here on SO itself.

```
static List<Patient> PatientsList()
    {
        List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
        return patientList;
    }

 private void AddAddOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the data on the patient, name etc.
        patient.PatientFirstName = PatientFirstNameInput.Text;
        patient.PatientLastName = PatientLastNameInput.Text;
        patient.PatientCopay = Convert.ToDecimal(PatientCopayInput.Text);
        patient.BillId = BillIdInput.Text;

        Charge charge;

        // Does the patient already have a Charge in their list?
        if (patient.ChargeList.Count == 0)
        {
            // - if not, add a new charge
            charge = new Charge();
            patient.ChargeList.Add(charge);
        }
        else
        {
            // - if that's the case, use the existing charge but update info
            charge = patient.ChargeList.First();
        }


        // Add a charge to the patient's list of charges
        charge.DateofService = DateofServiceInput.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        charge.PrimaryProcedureCode = PrimaryProcedureInput.Text;
        charge.PrimaryChargeCost = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryChargeInput.Text);
        charge.PrimaryChargeContractualAdjustment = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryAdjustmentInput.Text);
        charge.PrimaryPaymentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryPaidInput.Text);

        // Set the name of the Patient
        // Create a new Charge
        // Create an add-on charge and add it to the Charge

        AddonCharge newAddonCharge = new AddonCharge();
        newAddonCharge.AddonProcedureCode = AddonProcedureInput.Text;
        newAddonCharge.AddonChargeCost = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonChargeInput.Text);
        newAddonCharge.AddonContractualAdjustment = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonAdjustmentInput.Text);
        newAddonCharge.AddonPaymentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonPaidInput.Text);
        charge.AddonChargeList.Add(newAddonCharge);

        List<Patient> patientList = PatientsList();
        patientList.Add(patient);
        //newCharge.AddonChargeList.Add(newAddonCharge);
    }

 private void AddtoListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //return a new patient with null details
        Patient patient = new Patient();

        List<Patient> patientlist = PatientsList();
        // Show a messagebox with the string
        //MessageBox.Show(EDIToString());

    }
```

Comment: `PatientsList()` is making a new list each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous answers suggest, your issue is that you're recreating the patient list on each invocation. The `static` keyword doesn't change this.

I've changed your code to fix the issue, by initializing the patient list field once.

```
private List<Patient> PatientsList = new List<Patient>();

private void AddAddOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the data on the patient, name etc.
    patient.PatientFirstName = PatientFirstNameInput.Text;
    patient.PatientLastName = PatientLastNameInput.Text;
    patient.PatientCopay = Convert.ToDecimal(PatientCopayInput.Text);
    patient.BillId = BillIdInput.Text;

    Charge charge;

    // Does the patient already have a Charge in their list?
    if (patient.ChargeList.Count == 0)
    {
        // - if not, add a new charge
        charge = new Charge();
        patient.ChargeList.Add(charge);
    }
    else
    {
        // - if that's the case, use the existing charge but update info
        charge = patient.ChargeList.First();
    }


    // Add a charge to the patient's list of charges
    charge.DateofService = DateofServiceInput.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    charge.PrimaryProcedureCode = PrimaryProcedureInput.Text;
    charge.PrimaryChargeCost = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryChargeInput.Text);
    charge.PrimaryChargeContractualAdjustment = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryAdjustmentInput.Text);
    charge.PrimaryPaymentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(PrimaryPaidInput.Text);

    // Set the name of the Patient
    // Create a new Charge
    // Create an add-on charge and add it to the Charge

    AddonCharge newAddonCharge = new AddonCharge();
    newAddonCharge.AddonProcedureCode = AddonProcedureInput.Text;
    newAddonCharge.AddonChargeCost = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonChargeInput.Text);
    newAddonCharge.AddonContractualAdjustment = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonAdjustmentInput.Text);
    newAddonCharge.AddonPaymentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(AddonPaidInput.Text);
    charge.AddonChargeList.Add(newAddonCharge);

    List<Patient> patientList = PatientsList;
    patientList.Add(patient);
    //newCharge.AddonChargeList.Add(newAddonCharge);
}

private void AddtoListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //return a new patient with null details
    Patient patient = new Patient();

    List<Patient> patientlist = PatientsList;
    // Show a messagebox with the string
    //MessageBox.Show(EDIToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts with this static method:

```
static List<Patient> PatientsList()
{
    List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
    return patientList;
}
```

Every time you call it, will create a brand new empty list of patients.

So the following lines:

```
    List<Patient> patientList = PatientsList();
    patientList.Add(patient);
```

Will create a brand new empty list and then adds the patient to it. The next time it is called, the same things will happen again, with the previous patient no longer being stored.

Best way to fix your problem is to convert the `PatientsList()` method to a field as follows:

```
private readonly List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
```

As a field, the `patientList` field will initialised automatically when the class is constructed.

The [readonly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword is optional, but it basically prevents the field from being reassigned to something else.

From MSDN:

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a
>   field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the
>   fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the
>   declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Now when you want add patients to the list, you only need to call `patientList.Add(patient);` from you button click methods.

Answer (score -1):

You have a static method wich is used to create a patient list and it feels like you are expecting it to be called only once. This is not the case. Static just means it will be accessible without any instance of your class.

What you are looking for is having the list as a member of your class and creating it only if it has not been created before.

try adding outside of your methods

```
List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
```

and remove the call you do to PatientsList();